# good books about server architecture?

Tags: linux, network-design

when the traffic for a website grows i dont think one apache server in a vps is the way to go. i would like to know more about how i then should set up the server side architecture.

im not that much into hardware stuff (what kind of cables to use, different cpu architectures etc), but interested in the software architecture:

- what servers (apache, nginx, squid, varnish etc) to use and how they interact with each other
- one server in one machine?
- how many mysql servers.
- how many apache, nginx servers and so on.
- how the "machine court" looks like.

are there any good books about this area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a book though.

[highscalability.com](http://highscalability.com)

> This site tries to bring together all the lore, art, science, practice, and experience of building scalable websites into one place so you can learn how to build your website with confidence.

You can read about [youtube](http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture), [google](http://highscalability.com/google-architecture), [plenty of fish](http://highscalability.com/plentyoffish-architecture) architecture.

Comment: what a good resource! far better than any book i guess, cause its real practice and not just theoretical.